# Разница элементов массива

Tags: математика

Есть начальное значение массива, есть конечное значение массива, есть количество элементов и известно, что разность между каждыми соседями элементами равна.

Как найти эту разность (шаг, если хотите)? Математическую формулу, пожалуйста, не готовую функцию какого-либо языка.

---

Ребят, все спасибо, проблема возникла из-за изначально неправильно понятого задания. Перепробовал все, ничего не работало, а в итоге значение не туда подсовывал...

Answer (score 4):

Есть a<sub>0</sub> и a<sub>N-1</sub>. Между ними разность a<sub>N-1</sub>-a<sub>0</sub>, cостоящая из N-1 промежутка.

Делим (a<sub>N-1</sub>-a<sub>0</sub>)/(N-1).

Просто даже стыдно писать такие очевидные ответы... Ну представьте N посаженных деревьев, между которыми равные промежутки. Как их найти, если известно расстояние между первым и последним деревом? Задача для 2-3 класса...

Comment: куда 107 штук пригождается ?

Comment: а почему бы не делить на кол-во элементов ? тоесть на N а не на N-1 !?

Comment: @ampawd Т.е. если вы встанете от меня на расстоянии 2м, то промежуток между нами будет 1м?...

Answer (score 1):

Это обычная арифметическая прогрессия.
`a(n) ==  a(1) + (n - 1) * d`, где `a(n)` - конечное значение, `n` - к-ство элементов, а `d` - разница.
Тогда `d = (a(n) - a(1))/(n - 1)`